# Commander throws error for command with description

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, node-commander

Here is a simple example of adding command in nodejs using commander:

```
'use strict';

const {Command} = require('commander');

const run = () => {
    const program = new Command();

    console.log('CMD');
    program.command('cmd [opts...]')
        .action((opts) => {
            console.log('OPTS');
        });

    program.parse(process.argv);
};

run();
```

In this case everything works fine, but when I'm adding description and options, `commander` throws an error:

`program.command('cmd [opts...]', 'DESCRIPTION', {isDefault: true})`

```
node test-commander.js cmd opts

test-commander-cmd(1) does not exist, try --help
```

My env:

```
node v8.9.3
npm 5.3.0
commander 2.12.2
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the declared behavior of commander. From the npm page under [Git-style sub-commands](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander#git-style-sub-commands)...

> When .command() is invoked with a description argument, no  .action(callback) should be called to handle sub-commands, otherwise there will be an error. This tells commander that you're going to use separate executables for sub-commands, much like git(1) and other popular tools.
>   The commander will try to search the executables in the directory of the entry script (like ./examples/pm) with the name program-command, like pm-install, pm-search.

So, when you add a description like you have, it'll assume you have another executable file called `test-commander-cmd` for the sub command.

If commander's behavior is not what you were expecting, I might recommend looking into a package I published, called [wily-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wily-cli)... only if you're not committed to commander, of course ;)

Assuming your code rests in `file.js`, your example with [wily-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wily-cli) would look like this...

```
const cli = require('wily-cli');

const run = () => {
  cli
    .command('cmd [opts...]', 'DESCRIPTION', (options, parameters) => { console.log(parameters.opts); })
    .defaultCommand('cmd');
};

run();

// "node file.js option1 option2" will output "[ 'option1', 'option2' ]"
```

Answer (score 0):

As I landed this ancient thread experiencing the same issue, giving my answer it may be useful for others who will land here in their search.
You should add description not to `command` call, but with separate call

```js
command.description('Description Text');
```

In this case Commander behavior is different and it will not ignore the `action` call of command setup.

```js
const group = program.command('group');
group.command('add <item>`).description('Add something to group`).action(() => {
   //do something
});
group.command('remove <item>`).description('Remove something from group`).action(() => {
   //do something
});
```